# NameError: name 'xxxxx' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I'm trying run this code but it show me --NameError: name 'calcula_pagamento' is not defined--
I tried to declare this function, but without success.

```
str_horas= input('Digite as horas: ')
str_taxa=input('Digite a taxa: ')
#calcula_pagamento = ( )
total_salario = calcula_pagamento(str_horas,str_taxa)
def calcular_pagamento (qtd_horas, valor_hora):
    horas = float(qtd_horas)
    taxa = float(valor_hora)
    if horas <= 40:
        salario = horas*taxa
    else:
        h_excd = horas - 40
        salario = 40*taxa+(h_excd*(1.5*taxa))
        return salario
    print('O valor de seus rendimentos é R$',total_salario)
```

Comment: move the total_salario= calcula_pagamento... line down below the function. You are calling the function before you define it. The code runs top to bottom.   You also have written calcula_pagamento when the function is called calcular_pagamento. Make sure they are spelled the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call the function *after* you define it. Also as C Haworth pointed out, you have a typo when calling your function. I've corrected that below.

```
str_horas= input('Digite as horas: ')
str_taxa=input('Digite a taxa: ')
#calcula_pagamento = ( )

def calcular_pagamento (qtd_horas, valor_hora):
    horas = float(qtd_horas)
    taxa = float(valor_hora)
    if horas <= 40:
        salario = horas*taxa
    else:
        h_excd = horas - 40
        salario = 40*taxa+(h_excd*(1.5*taxa))

    return salario
    print('O valor de seus rendimentos é R$',total_salario)

total_salario = calcular_pagamento(str_horas,str_taxa)
```

Comment: There is also a typo between the function definition and calling it

Comment: @CHaworth good catch, thank you

Comment: Ok. But the function is not running yet, now: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\teste2.py", line 15, in <module>
    total_salario = calcular_pagamento(str_horas,str_taxa)
  File "C:\Users\rlpro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\teste2.py", line 13, in calcular_pagamento
    print("O valor de seus rendimentos é R$ ",total_salario,)
NameError: name 'total_salario' is not defined @chaworth

Comment: @RicardoProença probably because your return statement is not indented properly. Look at my current edit and move the return statement one tab back

Comment: It's ok ... I was trying to test with input values, but I need to tell them when I call the function